# DropDown filter level wise

Tags: oracle, dropdown, oracleforms

I want to design a form in which drop-down filter.I select Branch from one drop-down next drop-down of store should be shown only of that branch not whole stores.

[image]

```sql
PROCEDURE make_list IS
group_id recordgroup;
status number;
BEGIN
   group_id := Create_Group_From_Query('STORE','select STORE_NAME, TO_CHAR(STORE_ID) 
                                                  from inv_stores 
                                                 where BRANCH_ID = :BRANCH_ID'); 
   status := Populate_Group('STORE'); 
   Populate_List('STORE',group_id); 
exception when no_data_found then
      null;
END;
```

Comment: relace your 7th line by `Populate_List('STORE_ID','STORE');` just similar to my case(where 'STORE_ID' should be the name of `Store` list item in the image). Btw, `exception when no_data_found then null;` is redundant.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I've done as you said but not works.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Sir now showing error: FRM-41072 cannot create group STORE.

Comment: Are you sure the query is working independently ..? Btw you might need to alias to_char(store_id) (  such as `to_char(store_id) as str_id` )which I wonder why you're trying to make such a conversion ...

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan yes sir same query working for other field that working is perfect but now it is not working in this case of filter

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using lists of values. Walthrough is relatively simple:

- create Record Group (RG) queries which will select data you need

  - the second RG query should reference item which is populated by the first LoV; that's called "cascading"
- create List of Values (LoV) for each of those RGs
- attach LoVs to their items (there's a property in item's Property Palette)

That's all, I guess.

Comment: PROCEDURE make_list IS
group_id recordgroup;
status number;
BEGIN
         group_id := Create_Group_From_Query('STORE','select STORE_NAME, TO_CHAR(STORE_ID) from inv_stores where BRANCH_ID = :BRANCH_ID'); 
    status := Populate_Group('STORE'); 
    Populate_List('STORE_ID',group_id); 
exception when no_data_found then
      null;
END;   I'm trying this one

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you have two succesive list items namely `l_province` and `l_district`. In order to re-populate `l_district` item by subordinate districts with respect to each change of `l_province` item, `l_district` must be **Combo Box** list style. Keeping this syle, Deleting the present list items ( `Clear_List` method ) would be able to work.

So, Add a `WHEN-LIST-CHANGED` trigger under `l_province` item with the code :

```
Declare
    i            pls_integer;       
    status       pls_integer;
    group_id     RecordGroup;

Begin
    group_id := Create_Group_From_Query('g_province','Select province_code||' - '||province_name, 
                                                             province_code 
                                                        From tab_province Order By province_code');
    status := Populate_Group('g_province'); 
    Populate_List('l_province','g_province');    


    Clear_List('l_district');        

   i:=1;
   for c in ( select * from tab_district where province_code = :l_province 
               order by nlssort(district_name,'nls_sort=xturkish') ) -- replace `turkish` depending on your language. No needed for `english` case. 
   loop
     Add_List_Element( 'l_district', i , c.district_name, c.l_district_code ); 
     i:=i+1;
   end loop;

End;
```

Here I tried to show two styles for populating a list item.

**Update :** For your current case use create a parameter at Form level and use as :

```
PROCEDURE make_list IS
   group_id recordgroup;
   status   number;
BEGIN
  :parameter.p_branch_id := :branch_id;    
   group_id := Create_Group_From_Query('STORE','select store_name, to_char(store_id)                                     
                                                  from inv_stores 
                                                 where branch_id = :parameter.p_branch_id'); 
   status := Populate_Group('STORE'); 
   Populate_List('branch_id','STORE'); 

END;
```

Comment: ```PROCEDURE make_list IS
group_id recordgroup;
status number;
BEGIN
         group_id := Create_Group_From_Query('STORE','select STORE_NAME, TO_CHAR(STORE_ID) from inv_stores where BRANCH_ID = :BRANCH_ID'); 
    status := Populate_Group('STORE'); 
    Populate_List('STORE_ID',group_id); 
exception when no_data_found then
      null;
END;```    I'm trying this one and it is not working